# AngularFire2: Trying to paginate with duplicate causing issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is how I am trying to show 5 records per page

```
dbinstace.list(`obj/`, ref => ref.orderByChild(field) startAt(startKey)).limitToFirst(5)
```

I have records say

```
record: {{
  field: 0
},
{
  field: 0
},
{
  field: 0
},
{
  field: 1
},
{
  field: 1
},
{
  field: 1
},
{
  field: 1
},
{
  field: 2
},
{
  field: 2
},
{
  field: 2
}}
```

The issue with this code is it always starts the second page from `record[3]` even though `record[0]` to `record[4]` has been rendered on first page. Moreover with this approach once a run of same value of length greater than a page size come you can not go past that no matter how many time you query for next page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something but isnt the whole point of keys that they are unique identifiers or a record. Your data doesn't appear to have a key so you can add one and then the startKey will be able to work.

firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP can be used to generate the keys is required.